# Change subnet mask from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.255.255

Tags: networking, subnet

I am using a broadband connection and the subnet mask given to me by the broadband company is 255.255.255.0. I want to know if I change the subnet mask to 255.255.255.255 then what will be the effect on the internet connection?

And what is the difference between these two subnet masks?

Comment: Have you researched anything on what a subnet mask does?

Comment: Why do you ask? what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If your device lets you enter 255.255.255.255 as the subnet mask it won't be able to communicate with other devices on the network.

Answer (score 1):

> And what is the difference between these two subnet masks?

Your computer c a l c u l a t e s the route of every network packet. The subnet mask is an important part of the formula. If you do not define the subnet mask properly your network communication will not work.

255.255.255.0 = /24 <==> e.g. 172.16.1.0 - 172.16.1.255

255.255.255.255 = /32 <==> e.g. 172.16.1.10

The main difference between these two subnet masks is that they define two different networks. An IP address with a /32 mask defines a network that fits only one IP address.

An IP address with a /24 mask defines a different network that fits 256 IP addresses.

Take an example. Your computer has an IP address 192.168.1.1/24 and it would like to communicate with 192.168.1.2/24. They are in the same subnet therefore they do not need to turn to a gateway/router to communicate.

Despite that, if your computer has only one network interface and has the IP address 192.168.1.3/32 the packet will not be able leave your computer and therefore will not be able to communicate to other computers.

If you do not know anything about computer networking and respectively about the subnet mask I recommend to you do not touch it.

> I want to know if I change the subnet mask to 255.255.255.255 then what will be the effect on the internet connection?

If you change the subnet mask of your WAN IP from /24 to /32 you will not have internet connection. Your ISP defined that address like that with good reason.

Answer (score 0):

The "all ones" subnet mask (255.255.255.255) only works for point-to-point links, where there's only two devices on the link, so anything Device A transmits can only get to Device B, and anything Device B transmits can only get to Device A, because there's no way for there to be any other devices on that network link.

So if you're on, say, DSL, you may very well have a point-to-point link, possibly even over some form of the point-to-point protocol (PPP), such as PPPoA or PPPoE. So it *might* be fine to have the subnet mask on that PPP* link be 255.255.255.255. Note I'm only talking about the WAN link from your router, not the LAN side. Also, this doesn't apply to non-point-to-point WAN links, like perhaps DOCSIS and GPON.

It doesn't make sense to use 255.255.255.255 on a multi-way network link type, like a typical home Ethernet + Wi-Fi LAN. Since there are multiple devices on that link type, you would want to use a subnet mask that leaves enough host addresses for all the hosts on your home LAN.

Comment: Does an ipv4 /32 allow 2 devices? I was taught /30 was the smallest usable subnet.

Comment: It doesn't actually. A /31 with 'subnet-zero' devices is the smallest subnet for two devices. However, an all-ones will work for point-to-point links in certain implementations (but I wouldn't call it a "subnet") (ex. Cisco, Linux, perhaps others). See https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/dynamic-address-allocation-resolution/13711-40.html#subnetzero2